# Regex for [IMG] BBCode containing Base64 encoded Image strings

Tags: php, regex, base64, bbcode

I am using following Regex:-

```
\[img](.*.;base64.*.?)\[\/img]/mi
```

Now the sample text that I have is

```
This is some sample text. ([URL]http://www.example.com[/URL]) This is a sample page. The issues with this page are in following list.[LIST][*]Issue 1[IMG]http://www.example.com/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkBAMAAACCzIhnAAAAG1BMVEXMzMyWlpacnJy+vr6jo6PFxcW3t7eqqqqxsbHbm8QuAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAiklEQVRYhe3QMQ6EIBAF0C+GSInF9mYTs+1ewRsQbmBlayysKefYO2asXbbYxvxHQj6ECQMAEREREf2NQ/fCtp5Zky6vtRMkSJEzhyISynWJnzH6Z8oQlzS7lEc/fLmmQUSvc16OrCPqRl1JePxQYo1ZSWVj9nxrrOb5esw+eXdvzTWfTERERHRXH4tWFZGswQ2yAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC[/IMG][IMG]https://www.example.com/attachment/random_img.png[/IMG][IMG]http://www.example.com/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAACWBAMAAADOL2zRAAAAG1BMVEXMzMyWlpaqqqq3t7fFxcW+vr6xsbGjo6OcnJyLKnDGAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAABAElEQVRoge3SMW+DMBiE4YsxJqMJtHOTITPeOsLQnaodGImEUMZEkZhRUqn92f0MaTubtfeMh/QGHANEREREREREREREtIJJ0xbH299kp8l8FaGtLdTQ19HjofxZlJ0m1+eBKZcikd9PWtXC5DoDotRO04B9YOvFIXmXLy2jEbiqE6Df7DTleA5socLqvEFVxtJyrpZFWz/pHM2CVte0lS8g2eDe6prOyqPglhzROL+Xye4tmT4WvRcQ2/m81p+/rdguOi8Hc5L/8Qk4vhZzy08DduGt9eVQyP2qoTM1zi0/uf4hvBWf5c77e69Gf798y08L7j0RERERERERERH9P99ZpSVRivB/rgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==[/IMG][*]Issue 2[IMG]http://www.example.com/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8BAMAAADI0sRBAAAAJFBMVEXMzMyWlpbFxcWjo6O+vr63t7ecnJy0tLSenp6Xl5exsbGqqqqVdOLvAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAXUlEQVQ4jWNgGAWjYBTQByibGzsAKSbjYhNs0iYaLgZAitmpxRmbdHKikgCXtwKbmZAiNmlRRyUBBlMGxhDs0kmaLgZMVgxsSlOwGu4MdBq3tgILDqeNglEwCrADAH+uCwDFhiuPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC[/IMG][IMG]https://www.example.com/attachment/another_random_image.jpg[/IMG][IMG]http://www.example.com/image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyBAMAAADsEZWCAAAAG1BMVEXMzMyWlpaqqqq3t7exsbGcnJy+vr6jo6PFxcUFpPI/AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQUlEQVQ4jWNgGAWjgP6ASdncAEaiAhaGiACmFhCJLsMaIiDAEQEi0WXYEiMCOCJAJIY9KuYGTC0gknpuHwXDGwAA5fsIZw0iYWYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=[/IMG][/LIST]
```

So the case is this regex is not matching all the occurances of those Base64 strings that are in individual `[IMG]` BBCodes but it counts all as one. Can someone point me where I am wrong?
I just need to match those `[IMG]` BBCodes in which there is Base64 encoded content which I can identify through `;base64` substring match.

Comment: Use `'~\[img]((?:(?!\[img]).)*?;base64.*?)\[/img]~si'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JWORv/2).

Comment: "[" has special meaning in regexp, so you should probably protect them. And you may use regex101.com to test your regex.
Try : https://regex101.com/r/ROWSee/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Just tested - yours works perfectly. Also following one does work as well `/\[IMG\](.*?;base64.*?)\[\/IMG\]/mi` - so what's the difference between the two?

Comment: `\[IMG\](.*?;base64.*?)\[\/IMG\]` [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/OfB8CM/1), see the second match.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, this regex `'~\[img]((?:(?!\[img]).)*?;base64.*?)\[/img]~si'` is giving me "Catastrophic Backtracking" for several images. What could be the reason?

Comment: @khalid Because you should actually use a BBcode parser. We can further [fine tune](https://regex101.com/r/7JWORv/3) the regex, but is it worth it?